# Run web application on android

Tags: android

I developed web service that works on windows using vs2005 .can I run it on android mobile?

Comment: Can please edit the title.You are asking about the web service & title is running web application

Comment: Why not!? if its SOAP, use KSOAP2 Android library

Comment: @Shreikh using kSoap2 library is for consuming web service not running web service application.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run a Web Service application created with Visual Studio on an Android device.  You can however **consume** any individual web service from an Android application if configured properly on the server.